# Demande de divorce - why DE

Tags: grammaire

Why do we say:

> Demande de divorce

and not:

> Demande d'un divorce

?

Comment: Can someone explain me when we use demande de when demande d'un/d'une or just demande LE divorce? :(

Answer (score 4):

Because with the second form, that might mean a divorce itself is asking something (request from a divorce) which is more than dubious.

*Divorce* is here to be taken as generic, uncounted substantive. A divorce is asked, not some specific divorce.

You might however say both *demande de divorce à l'amiable* and *demande d'un divorce à l'amiable* because in that latter case, it is about a specific divorce, not a generic one.

Similarily, when *demande* is a conjugated verb and not a substantive, *le* is used when divorce is generic and *un* if a specific kind of divorce:

> Il demande le divorce.

It is rarely:

> Il demande un divorce.

but one will say:

> Il demande un divorce rapide.

and definitely not:

> Il demande le divorce rapide.

Comment: pretty sure the OP misplaced that question mark.

Comment: One could argue that using "de" gives us a similar ambiguity, or even that "d'un" might not be so ambiguous after all. Usually, if you specify the one who makes the demand, you will not say "demande de pierre" or "demande d'un banquier", but "demande **par/de la part d'** un banquier (e.g. "**demande d'une journée de congé par/de la part d'un  banqiuer**). The fact that we don't use "d'un divorce" is merely due to the fact that there can only be one divorce, so "de divorce" is specific enough.

Comment: So demande is always with "DE"? never with a construction d'un, d'une or des?

Comment: Answer updated, *Demande d'un* might also be used.

Comment: Can you explain me in what meanings?

Comment: It can be used when a specific kind of thing is asked.